# Loop over all attributes of elements of certain selectors and substract 1 from all integers in the attribute value

Tags: jquery, nested, each

I need to search through all attributes of labels and inputs of my `$('#survey-wrapper')` div and subtract any numbers that occur in the attributes value by 1.

This is what the DOM tree looks like:

```
div
  form
    ol
      li
        fieldset
        legend
        label <-- Should be searched
        input <-- Should be searched
        ul
          li
            input <-- Should be searched
            label <-- Should be searched
```

Here's my attempt:

```
$('#removeOneQuestion').on('click', function() {

        $('#survey-wrapper form ol').find('li').children('label, input').each(function() {

            $(this).each(function(i) { //Also tried with just $.each but it gives the same result
                var attribs = $(this).attr();

                var num = attribs[i].match(/[0-9 -()+]+$/);
                    parseInt(num);
                    num--;
            });
        });
    });
```

But I can't get anything inside the nested `.each()` to work. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong because I haven't been able to find a solution that works. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You would have better to post relevant HTML markup in question so we could see which attributes you are talking about. Anyway, sounds like a XY problem  http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but it seems like your inner loop is only going to be running against one element - either the label or input under the first level of `li`. Not that this addresses the issue, it just seems strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/4nfm2a3r/

```
$("form ol li input, form ol li label").each(function () {

    $.each(this.attributes, function(i, attrib){

     var num = attrib.value.match(/[0-9 -()+]+$/);
     parseInt(num);
     num--;
     alert(num);

  });
});
```